# TFS 2008 Subfolder Permissions

Tags: security, team-foundation-server

I am a TFSAdmin and when I have a TFS project in which a subfolder needs specific permissions to deny some users. So, I right click on the folder in question hit `Properties`, and click the `Security` tab.

There I select the `Windows User or Group` radio, then click `Add`.
I put in the AD User that I want specific permissions for and hit `Check Names`. That resolves, so I click `OK`.

Next, I select the permissions to `Allow` or `Deny` below in the `Permissions for` list.
I hit OK.

The permission are honored by TFS, this user no longer has `PendChange` permissions and I was expecting.

The odd thing is, I was expecting to be able to go back into the `Security` tab and see that `User` in the list of `Users and Groups` and see the current state. But the list is always empty. Not sure why, but the permissions are definitely being honored, I can re-add the user with different permissions and those are also honored.

Any ideas why the current users are not showing up in the `Users and Groups` list under the `Security` tab for a folder's properties?

I also used the `tf permission $\...` to see if there were any permissions but it always returns

`There are no permissions set for this item` 
`(Inherit: Yes)`

I see this error `TF200035: An error occured when synchronizing the following Active Directory identity: Team Foundation Valid Users. Exception Message: Error in the application.`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a synchronization issue between TFS and AD, or the "TfsJobAgent" is going crazy, the steps to troubleshoot it is long so I'll just paste you a link to it here: http://nakedalm.com/active-directory-groups-not-syncing-with-team-foundation-server-2010/

If the above link did not help, I would suggest to use a third party tool to manage your security permissions on the server, it might be that VS is not reporting the applied permissions correctly.

This tool will control TFS, Reporting and SharePoint sites all at the same time: http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/releases/view/57795

Hope this helps,

Comment: I see this error `TF200035: An error occured when synchronizing the following Active Directory identity: Team Foundation Valid Users. Exception Message: Error in the application`.